# Possible to use a single sqlalchemy session and table across identical schemas?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, session, sqlalchemy

I'm designing a database that has an API layer over it to get data from the tables. The database is postgres. Every night, we do a batch ETL process to update the data in the database. Due to some complications that aren't worth mentioning, the ETL process involves wiping out all of the data and rebuilding things from scratch.

Obviously, this is problematic for the API because if the API queries the database during the rebuilding phase, data will be missing.

I've decided to solve this by using two schemas. The "finished" schema (let's call this schema A) and the "rebuilding" schema (let's call this schema B). My ETL process looks like this:

```
1. Create schema B as an exact replica of schema A
2. Completely rebuild the data in schema B
3. In a transaction, drop schema A and rename schema B to schema A
```

The problem I'm currently running into is that I'm using sqlalchemy Session and Table objects, and the tables are bound to schema A by virtue of their metadata.

I would like to be able to do `session.add(obj)` and have it add that data to schema B. After all, schema A and schema B are exactly the same so the table definitions should be valid for both.

I'm wondering if anyone has any recommendations on how I can use sqlalchemy's session object and/or table objects to *dynamically* select which schema I should be using.

I still want sessions/tables to point to schema A because the same code is reused in the API layer. I only want to use schema B during this one step.

Comment: can you set `Model.__table__.schema` ?

Comment: Thanks - That works, but it's not the cleanest solution. It did give me some ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by wrapping my table definitions in functions that accept a sqlalchemy metadata object and return the table definition bound to that metadata object.